# MySQL INSERT SELECT statement throws Error 1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 2

Tags: mysql, select, insert, reverse

Basically, I have a table called document which contains a column named as "host". I have created another column named as "rev_host" and all I want is to store the reversed strings from "host" to "rev_host". For example, if the "host" value is "www.cmu.edu", I want to save "ude.umc.www" to "rev_host". I then use a statement

```
INSERT INTO document (rev_host) SELECT REVERSE(host) from document;
```

This statement throws the 1062 error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 2
```

What is the problem of this statement? If I cannot insert in this way. What is the right way to perform this insertion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything particularly prohibiting you from using the reversed string based on the original 'www.cmu.edu' rather than using a different table?  It seems that if the conversion is always that consistent (REVERSE), you can save yourself the extra storage and inserts by just doing the REVERSE when you need it (selects, etc). This would follow the practice "don't store what you can calculate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query inserts a whole bunch of new lines in the table, thereby introducing duplicate keys. if you want to update just one column and keep your previous entries use `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE document SET rev_host=REVERSE(host);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I was almost there, I was using the statement below: UPDATE document SET rev_host=(SELECT REVERSE(host) FROM document); but got a "syntax mistake" error. Your answer really works!